# use of unstable library feature - how can I fix those?

Tags: rust

I got a bunch of errors again:

```
$ cargo build
error: use of unstable library feature 'std_misc'
use std::time::duration::Duration;
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
error: use of unstable library feature 'convert': waiting on RFC revision
let my_let1 = aaa(bbb.as_str(), ccc, ddd.eee);
                                                        ^~~~~~~~
error: use of unstable library feature 'convert': waiting on RFC revision
let let1 = aaa.as_slice();
                                             ^~~~~~~~~~
error: use of unstable library feature 'convert': waiting on RFC revision
let let1 = str::from_utf8(aaa.as_slice()).unwrap();
                                                ^~~~~~~~~~
```

How to solve them? What does it mean: `add #![feature(collections)] to the crate attributes to enable` - what crates? I don't have the source code of my crates. How would other people compile my library on their machines then?

And oddly enough this also throws an error:

```
src/lib.rs:1:1: 1:31 error: unstable feature
src/lib.rs:1 #![feature(convert, std_misc)]
```

when I add it at the top my library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using Rust stable. In that case unstable features can't be enabled.

For `Duration` you can use the [time crate on crates.io](https://crates.io/crates/time) by adding it to the dependencies in your Cargo.toml.

In the other cases, you should be able to simply use `&aaa` and `&bbb` respectively to get slices out of Vec or String.
e.g.

```
let b = String::from("foo"); // b is a String
let c: &str = &b; // c expects a &str; b is automatically dereferenced
```

Comment: **For Duration you can use the time crate on crates.io by adding it to the dependencies in your Cargo.toml.** - that's what I'm doing as you can see  --> `use std::time::duration::Duration;`

Comment: oh, I shouldn't use `std::time::duration::Duration`, right? But doesn't the crate `time` contain std::time::duration::Duration?

Comment: you should `use time::duration::Duration;`, otherwise you're still referencing the deprecated Duration in std