# Can't Insert an Item into the Hashmap in Rust

Tags: rust

I'm new to Rust so please bare with me.
I'm trying to do what I would consider to be quite simple - insert an item into a HashMap. When I try to insert an item, it just freezes and I can't seem to figure out why.

VSCode isn't picking up any errors, been googling around and can't seem to find anything that might indicate what might be the issue.

I feel like that it might be related the the Mutex but really not sure. Below is a snippet of the relevant bit of the code.

```rust
use lazy_static::lazy_static;
use std::collections::{HashMap, HashSet};
use std::net::TcpStream;
use std::sync::Mutex;

lazy_static! {
    static ref SUBSCRIPTIONS: Mutex<HashMap<String, HashSet<String>>> = Mutex::new(HashMap::new());
}

pub struct Subscription {}

impl Subscription {

    fn is_channel_registered(&self, channel: &String) -> bool {
        SUBSCRIPTIONS.lock().unwrap().contains_key(channel)
    }

    pub fn add_subscription(&self, client: &TcpStream, channel: &String) {
        let mut subscriptions = SUBSCRIPTIONS.lock().unwrap();

        // Check if the a key for the channel already exists. If not create it.
        if !self.is_channel_registered(&channel) {
            subscriptions.insert(channel.to_string(), HashSet::new());
        }
}
```

Now, I am trying to test this using a unittest.
Below is that chunk of code:

```rust
#[cfg(test)]
mod subscription_tests {
    use super::*;
    use std::net::TcpStream;

    #[test]
    fn test_add_subscription() {
        let client = TcpStream::connect("localhost:8080").unwrap();
        let channel: "test_channel".to_string();
           
        Subscription {}.add_subscription(&client, &channel);
    }
}
```

I've commented out a bunch of code to try and find the issue by process of elimination, but it really looks like the issue is the actual code in the initial block.

Welp! I'm hoping this is enough to reproduce, but just incase [here is the code](https://github.com/Salaah01/rusty-pub-sub/blob/master/src/server/state.rs).

Comment: Nitpick: Don't use lazy_static, use once_cell, it's going to be part of std.

Comment: Can you extract a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Couldn't figure out how to use once_cell, it kept moaning saying that it's expecting a BANG.

Comment: Not a macro, just `static S: Lazy<T> = Lazy::new(|| { ... });`

Comment: Is yelling about me using an unstable feature (once_cell) when I did `use std::lazy::Lazy;` and basically won't compile.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30975088/use-of-unstable-library-feature-how-can-i-fix-those This seems to suggest it's not possible to use an unstable feature.

Comment: In other news, I've edited the code to hopefully make it easier to dig through.

Comment: I didn't meant to use the std's version (though that's certainly possible, just requires nightly), but to use the crate, so when the version in std gets stabilized, you'll just need to replace one line (or two).

Comment: You haven't given us a reproducible example, so it's going to be extremely difficult for anybody to give a solid answer. Try using the debugger (lldb works great in vscode with rust, just get the extension) and breakpoints to figure out exactly where it's blocking and then work from there. In search of a reproducible, rip out the part that's connecting to a TCP server (which could be part of the problem, but also nobody here has your sever to connect to).

Comment: My crystal ball says `is_channel_registered` is also trying to access `SUBSCRIPTIONS` and is therefore deadlocking itself. But its hard to be certain without a complete example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: woops, just edited the question and added the function.
Do I have to explicitly clear the mutex lock? I thought when the function finishes executing, it auto unlocks?

Comment: The function (`add_subscription`) holding the first lock *is still running* when the second function (`is_channel_registered`) attempts to acquire the lock a second time. Both functions can't lock the mutex at the same time (unless it is a reentrant mutex, which `std::sync::Mutex` is not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`is_channel_registered()` tries to lock the mutex while it's already locked. That results in a deadlock.

Either pass the unlocked value explicitly to it:

```rust
impl Subscription {
    fn is_channel_registered(subscriptions: &HashMap<String, HashSet<String>>, channel: &String) -> bool {
        subscriptions.contains_key(channel)
    }
    pub fn add_subscription(&self, client: &TcpStream, channel: &String) {
        let mut subscriptions = SUBSCRIPTIONS.lock().unwrap();

        // Check if the a key for the channel already exists. If not create it.
        if !Self::is_channel_registered(&*subscriptions, &channel) {
            subscriptions.insert(channel.to_string(), HashSet::new());
        }
    }
}
```

Or lock it inside `add_subscription()` only *after* `is_channel_registered()` is used:

```rust
impl Subscription {
    fn is_channel_registered(&self, channel: &String) -> bool {
        SUBSCRIPTIONS.lock().unwrap().contains_key(channel)
    }

    pub fn add_subscription(&self, client: &TcpStream, channel: &String) {
        // Check if the a key for the channel already exists. If not create it.
        if !self.is_channel_registered(&channel) {
            SUBSCRIPTIONS.lock().unwrap().insert(channel.to_string(), HashSet::new());
        }
}
```